# Importing huge dataset from JSON to Cloud Firestrore

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to import a large JSON file(177k record) to cloud firestore, firstly I found the code below;

**Uploading Code**

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./service_key.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "my service key"
});

const firestore = admin.firestore();
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, "files");

fs.readdir(directoryPath, function(err, files) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log("Unable to scan directory: " + err);
    }

    files.forEach(function(file) {
        var lastDotIndex = file.lastIndexOf(".");

        var menu = require("./files/" + file);

        menu.forEach(function(obj) {
            firestore
                .collection('academicians2')

            .add({ 'department': obj['department'], 'designation': obj['designation'], 'field': obj['field'], 'name': obj['name'], 'university': obj['university'], 'reviewList': [], 'rating': 0 })
                .then(function(docRef) {
                    console.log("Document written");
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
                });
        });
    });
});
```

but after uploading 10-15k records started to giving errors,(Memory error I guess), So I decided to schedule cloud functions for every 1.2 seconds as timeout and batch write this JSON to firestore, but really have no idea how to get 499 rows for each run from my JSON.

**Scheduled Cloud Function**

```
/* eslint-disable */
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { user } = require("firebase-functions/lib/providers/auth");
admin.initializeApp();
const firestore = admin.firestore();
const userRef = admin.firestore().collection('academicians2');

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 1.2 seconds').onRun((context) => {
//do i need to create for loop for batch or how can i approach to solve this problem
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

- Make the scheduled function get 500 records at a time with a "start after" clause.
- Perform a batch write to the db (batch writes are limited to 500 as you may know)
- If successful, copy the last record (or a reference to the last record: ex: record's ID) of those 500 records into a document in your db. It can be a document called "upload_tracker" with a field called "last_uploaded".
- On subsequent operations: the function queries that `last_uploaded` record from your db, then performs another operation starting AFTER that last record.

Notes:

. The scheduled function can write multiple batches before terminating if you want to finish quickly.

. In your Google Cloud Console / Cloud Functions, you may want to extend the function's timeout value to 9 minutes, if you know it's going to run for a long time.

. The document ID's should reflect your "record ID's" if you have them, to make sure there are no duplicates.

Comment: Solved issue with Timer function in a flutter, thanks anyway